# Return the array position of the containing array

Tags: php, arrays

Assuming I give you the following array:

```
$array = array (
    array (
      'key' => 'value'
    ),
    array (
      'key' => 'another value'
    ),
    array (
      'key' => 'yet another value'
    ),
    array (
      'key' => 'final value'
    )
);
```

What I want from this array is the position of the array with the value supplied. So If I am searching `$array` for the value of `"yet another value"` the result should be: `2` because the matching array is at position 2.

I know to do the following:

```
foreach ($array as $a) {
    foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
        if ($v ===  "yet another value") {
            return $array[$a]; // This is what I would do, but I want
                               //  the int position of $a in the $array.
                               //  So: $a == 2, give me 2.
        }
    }
}
```

### Update:

the key is always the same

Comment: is key always the same?

Comment: @n-dru yes the key is always the same

Comment: have you decided yet which answer is OK for you? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do this, if the keys are the same:

```
$v = "yet another value";
$a = array_search(array("key"=>$v),$array);
echo $a;//2
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1c37819f25369725effa5acef012f9ce323f5425

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $pos => $a) {
    foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
        if ($v ===  "yet another value") {
            return $pos;
        }
    }
}
```

This should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want position of array then use count like:-

```
var count = 0;
foreach ($array as $a) {
    foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
        if ($v ===  "yet another value") {
            return count; 
        }
       count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said that key is always the same, so you can declare a variable outside loop like so.

```
$position = 0;
foreach ($array as $a) {
    foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
        if ($v ===  "yet another value") {
            return $position;
        }
    }
    $position++;
}
```